# how to has n images for each item

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models named Tour and Agency
each Tour and each Agency can have n images
how can I implement this?
should I define a model like this:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    Image=models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
```

and add this field to Tour and Agency models?like this:

```
Gallery=models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

If I do this,when adding each Tour or Agency we have the list of all of images in Gallery
I just wanna can add n images for each item
how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this, depending on whether you want to re-use images between Tours and Agencies, and whether it makes sense to have one Image class or two. Without knowing more about your use case, I might do it like this:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    "Represents a set of images."
    # maybe a title or other fields?

class Image(models.Model):
    "Represents one image."
    # field names are usually lowercase, for clarity
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')
    # you might want more fields here, e.g. title, alt_text, etc

class Tour(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery)

class Agency(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery)
```

This sets up an intermediary model called `Gallery` which both `Tour` and `Agency` can refer to. If you wanted to allow more than one `Gallery` per `Tour` or `Agency`, or if you wanted to re-use galleries between different objects, you could use a `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField`. If you wanted to share images between galleries, you could use a `ManyToManyField` instead of a `ForeignKey` in the `Image` class.

Comment: OneToOneField cause an Image for each Item,but I wanna each Item has n images,if I use foreignkey I can have n images for each Item,but I think when adding an item,showing all other images is not a good idea,I wanna add n images for each item without seeing other images.

Comment: In this case the OneToOneField is between a Tour and a Gallery (a set of n images). Each Gallery has n Images that relate to the specific Tour or Agency - not all the images in the system.

Comment: why did U use Gallery model? I think the Image model was enough. would U mind describe more?

Comment: U know? I need no extra information like title about each set of images,I just need a set of images for each Tour or Agency.

Comment: Without the gallery model, the Image model needs ForeignKeys on both Tour and Agency, with neither required, and you'd have to add a new field for every other model that needed n Images. This way is cleaner from a data normalization standpoint.